# Dynamically created method argument

Tags: python, methods

I'm creating a series of buttons in a loop with the iterator variable `i`. In this loop, I define a method `click()`.

```
i = 0
while(i < 10):
    button = button()
    def click():
        anotherMethod(i)
    button.onClick = click
    i += 1
```

The problem is `i` seems to always be 9 (Which makes sense). I need `i` to "stick" to the iteration in which it was created for each method. I feel as if I'm not only missing something obvious, but I'm also asking a duplicate question. I just don't know what to search for.

Comment: `button = new button()` is not valid Python. Also, the code in your question causes an infinite loop. What's more, you aren't using the `button` variable anywhere, which makes me think that you're actually placing he button in the GUI _after the loop_.

Comment: you are not incrementing `i` either. Add `i += 1`

Comment: I corrected the code, ffr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a default argument in the function you're defining in your loop. The default value will preserve the value of `i` at the time the function is defined, even if it gets redefined later on:

```
for i in range(10): # do you really need to be using a while loop?
    def click(i=i): # use a default argument here, to save the current i value
        anotherMethod(i) # this refers to the argument i, not the loop variable i
    button.onClick = click
```

Comment: Thanks! And the little block of code I put in my question was just written (admittedly poorly) to explain what I wanted. More or less pseudocode.